# jQuery - use title attribute as text on hover but only within same parent

Tags: jquery

Need some help coming up with this jQuery, at one point I almost had it working except the title was placed as text in every `<p class="category-flag-text"></p>` on the page not just within the article, but have been unable to even get back to that point.

When hovering over `.category-icons a` I want to use the title attribute of `.category-icons a` as text for `<p class="category-flag-text"></p>` within the same parent article.

```
<article class="post-1">
  <div class="category-flags">
    <p class="category-flag-text"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="category-icons">
    <a href="http:/www..." title="Category One">
      <img src="http:/www..." alt="Category One" title="Category One">
    </a>
    <a href="http:/www..." title="Category Two">
      <img src="http:/www..." alt="Category Two" title="Category Two">
    </a>
  </div>
</article>

<article class="post-2">
  <div class="category-flags">
    <p class="category-flag-text"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="category-icons">
    <a href="http:/www..." title="Category One">
      <img src="http:/www..." alt="Category One" title="Category One">
    </a>
    <a href="http:/www..." title="Category Two">
      <img src="http:/www..." alt="Category Two" title="Category Two">
    </a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly straightforward.  Just use `$(this).closest('article')` to locate the closest article ancestor.  Then, you can find the `<p>` you want.

```
$(".category-icons a").on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).closest('article').find('.category-flag-text')
        .text($(this).attr('title'));
}).on('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).closest('article').find('.category-flag-text').text('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/bnB5h/

Comment: ahh .closest(), wasn't familiar with that, that's amazing, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.category-icons a').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('article').find('p.category-flag-text').text($(this).prop('title'));
  }, function(){
    $(this).closest('article').find('p.category-flag-text').html('');
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/akoton/1/edit

Comment: This appears to be interchangeable with Explosion Pills example, thanks.